# In c++, which reasons is true that the singleton(static instance) will be destroy once the program exit

Tags: c++, design-patterns, static, singleton, destructor

Thanks in advance!

Referring to Effective c++ item 4, Scott Meyers said all static variable/instance will be destroyed once main() exit. Here, we assume the singleton is only used in main().

Indeed, we know that if we use both two following forms of singleton, the instance will be destroyed automatically once the main() exit. But I want to distinguish two reasons below, which one is the direct reason to free the singleton? BTW, what is the difference between this two forms?

**Reason:**

1. normal instance will be destroyed once main() exit. (Not related to static)
2. all static variable/instance will be destroyed once main() exit.

**case 1:**

> //Singleton.h

```
class Singleton
{
private:
   Singleton();
   ~Singleton();
public:
   Singleton& Instance()
   {
      Return instance_;
   }
   static Singleton instance_;
};
```

> //Singleton.c

```
Singleton Singleton::instance_
```

**Instance destruction step:**

1. Referring to Effective c++ item 4, static instance_ will be free by compiler. 
   This is reason 2.

**case 2:**

> //Singleton.h

```
class Singleton
{
private:
   Singleton();
   ~Singleton();
public:
   Singleton& Instance()
   {
      static Singleton instance_;
      Return instance_;
   }

};
```

**Instance destruction step:**

1. The singleton 's destructor is called once program exit.
2. Then the destructor will free all the member, but no member inside class. This is reason 1.
3. Then the compiler will free all the static variable/instance, including instance_, this is not the job of class destructor. This is reason 2.

Answer (score 1):

From the C++11 Standard:

> **3.6.3 Termination**
>
> 1 Destructors (12.4) for initialized objects (that is, objects whose lifetime (3.8) has begun) with `static` storage duration are called as a result of returning from `main` and as a result of calling `std::exit` (18.5).

In both case, the singleton objects are of `static` storage duration.

In the first case, the object is always initialized. The destructor of the object will be always called at termination time.

In the second case, the object will be initialized only if `Singleton::Instance()` is called at least once. Otherwise the object will remain uninitialized. The destructor of the object won't be called if the object is not initialized. If the object is initialized, the destructor will be called at termination time.

Comment: @R Sahu Thanks! static storage class is a class with static variable, right?

Comment: @Edision the use of *class* in *static storage class* is the English usage of the word, not the C++ usage of the word. You can also have a `static int var = 10;`. The storage class of `var` is static.

Comment: @Edision If singleton objects are not static, will ther still follow this rule? That is destructor of the object will be always called at termination time?

Comment: @Edison, if the singleton object is not of `static` duration, it will be destructed as soon you return from the function.